# An integral equals 0

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to prove that if $\gamma$ is a curve with $trace(\gamma)$ a parallel segment to the y axis then
$$\int_{\gamma}f(x,y)dx=0$$
I'm completely lost here. The only thing that came to my mind was that $\gamma$ must be something of the form $\gamma(t)=(x_{0},t)$ where $t\in[a,b]$ and $x_{0}, a, b$ are fixed points, but I don't really know how to proceed from here.
Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: What is $f$? How is it related to $\gamma$?

Comment: Note the integral is with respect to $x$, not t

Answer (score 1):

Write $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$. Then$$f(x,y)dx=f(x(t),y(t))\dot{x}(t)dt.$$ As the image of $\gamma$ is contained in a line parallel to the $y$ axis, we have $\dot{x}(t)=0$.